# Angular ng-select2 search on open

Tags: angular, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

i want that the user directly can search when ng-select2 opens.
this time the user opens the ng-select2 and needs to click into the searchfield with the mouse and can search - but the search field should get focus directly on opening the ng-select2.

Is there an option to do this? I don't find something on google :(

this is my actual code:
HTML:

```
      <ng-select2 
      [(ngModel)]="AUEEquip"
      (ngModelChange)="filterrole()"
      name="AUEEquip"
      [allowClear]=true
      [data]="equips"
      [options]="options"
      [placeholder]="'Please choose your equipment'"
      style="text-align: left;">
      </ng-select2>
```

TS:

```
  options = {
    width: '100%',
    multiple: false,
    tags: false
  };
  equips: Select2OptionData[] = [];
  AUEEquip: string = '0';
```

Comment: any error on browser console ?

Comment: No, the ng-select2 works finde and the search also works - i just want to "jump" directly in the search field on open the ng-select2

Comment: Like, when we click on dropdown then inside select first control is textbox and needs to selects it automatically.

Comment: when i click the ng-select2 element and the dropdown opens yes there is a textbox for search but it doesn't focus automatically - but i want it to focus the searchfield automatically. There is no output in console.

Comment: `NgSelect2Module` did you imported this inside module ?

Comment: and any other module you are using in your project, with importing `NgSelect2Module` inside any feature module ?

Comment: i have imported this ```import { NgSelect2Module } from 'ng-select2';``` in my app.module.ts and use it in app.component.html and ts. i have also imported the same in app.module.ts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232270/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-manuel-weitzel).

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ViewChild`

```
<ng-select2 #chooseInput
      [(ngModel)]="AUEEquip"
      (ngModelChange)="filterrole()"
      name="AUEEquip"
      [allowClear]=true
      [data]="equips"
      [options]="options"
      [placeholder]="'Please choose your equipment'"
      style="text-align: left;">
      </ng-select2>
```

in component

```
@ViewChild('chooseInput')
chooseInput: any;

ngOnInit() {

//focus the element
this.chooseInput.nativeElement.focus();

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this does not work for me. i habe imported ViewChild and added the code you wrote but when i open the ng-select2 the search field does not get focus automatically like i want